# set center text Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to set layout Wedding Oraganizer , Prewedding text and Our services button to MainAxisAlignment.center and 345 Moo layout in bottom........................................................................................................................................

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink[200],
          body: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 40, 30, 10),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Wedding Organizer',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 35,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Pre-wedding, Photo, Party',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                        fontSize: 25.5,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Our services',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                            fontSize: 17,
                            color: Colors.white)),
                    color: Colors.red,
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Text('345 Moo 1 Tasud Chiang Rai, Thailand',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                            fontSize: 17,
                            color: Colors.grey[300])),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ))),
    );
  }
}
```

My result

[image]

I want to output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Spacer` widget to put spaces in between the views instead of using an `Expanded` and `Align` widget on the same `Text`.

I made modifications to your code and came up with the desired output:

```dart
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink[200],
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 40, 30, 10),
        child: SizedBox.expand( // new line
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Spacer(), // new line
              Text(
                'Wedding Organizer',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 35,
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
              Text(
                'Pre-wedding, Photo, Party',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                    fontSize: 25.5,
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Our services',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                        fontSize: 17,
                        color: Colors.white)),
                color: Colors.red,
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              Spacer(), // new line
              Text('345 Moo 1 Tasud Chiang Rai, Thailand',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                      fontSize: 17,
                      color: Colors.grey[300]))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

RESULT:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is a code what you want.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink[200],
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 40, 30, 10),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Wedding Organizer',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 35,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Pre-wedding, Photo, Party',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                          fontSize: 25.5,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('Our services',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                              fontSize: 17,
                              color: Colors.white)),
                      color: Colors.red,
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Text('345 Moo 1 Tasud Chiang Rai, Thailand',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                      fontSize: 17,
                      color: Colors.grey[300])),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```